# Is Random Forest a linear or non linear regression model

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, random-forest, decision-tree, non-linear-regression

As decision trees are non linear models so Random Forest  should also be nonlinear methods in my opinion. But at some articles i have read otherwise. Can anyone explain how are they nonlinear or not .

or in other words Is Random Forest for linear or non linear data .

If i have a variable A (dependent) and other independent variables B and C and so on . How would RF fit a regression on these  variables in the data.

Comment: I think the question does not make sense - it's a model by it self, and not a linear regression model. So I don't think I understand the question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Claiming that RF is a *linear* model is absurd; care to share the exact sources you say you have read so?

Answer (score 3):

What RF does is to devide your data into square boxes.
When you then get a new datapoint it follows the yes/no-answers and ends up in a box.

In classification, it counts how many of each class thats in each box, and the majority of the classes is the prediciton.

When doing regression, it takes the mean of the values in each box.

In a regression setting you have the following equation

```py
y = b0 + x1*b1 + x2*b2 +.. + xn*bn
```

where `xi` is your feature "i" and `bi` is the coefficient to `xi`.

A linear regression is linear in the *coefficients* but say we have the following regression

```py
y=x0 +x1*b1 + x2*cos(b2)
```

that is not a linear regression since it is not linear in the coefficient `b2`.

To check if it is linear then the derivative of `y` with respect to `bi` should be independent of `bi` for all `bi`, i.e take the first example (the linear one):

```py
dy/db1 = x1
```

which is independent of `b1` (this give the same answer for all `dy/dbi`) but the second example

```py
# y=x0 +x1*b1 + x2*cos(b2)
dy/db2 = x2*(-sin(b2))
```

which is *not* independent of `b2` thus not a linear regression.

As you can see RF and linear regression is two different things and the linearity of a regression has nothing to do with a RF (or the other way round that matter)